# How to fix a problem with Python in PyCharm with black parts of window down and up?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, screen

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

from pygame import display

pygame.init()   #pokrecemo modul pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((round(800),(600))) #varijabla koju smo nazvali screen #definisemo na rezoluciju 800x600

#pozadina

background = pygame.image.load('background.png') #<a href='https://pngtree.com/so/background'>background png from pngtree.com</a>
pygame.display.set_caption("Osvoji Svemir") # naziv prozora
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo.png') # definisemo ikonicu
pygame.display.set_icon(icon) #pozivamo ikonicu da se pojavi

pygame.display.update()
# Igrac

playerImg = pygame.image.load('spaceship1.png')

playerX = 370
playerY = 500
playerX_change = 0

# Neprijatelj

enemyImg = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
enemyX = random.randint(0, 800) # ubacio sam random modul kako bi se neprijatelj pojavljivao na drugom mestu uvek
enemyY = random.randint(50, 150) # gornje kordinate su za X, a ove- donje za Y osu- da se na "random"- nasumicno pojavljuju
# defininisemo pozicije igraca naseg malog spejsatla
playerX_change = 0
playerY_change = 1

# definisemo pokrete neprijatelja, malih (u nasem slucaju- plavih)

enemyX_change = 0.4
enemyY_change = 40
def player(x,y):
    screen.blit(playerImg, (x, y))

def enemy(x,y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg, (x, y))

# Petlja igre (game loop)

running = True
while running:

screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) # prva i osnovna pozadina ekrana  ako redom idemo to je (CRVENA,PLAVA, ZELENA) u kodu
#pozadina za igricu (interaktivna pozadina koja je velicine ekrana kojeg smo definisali (800x600) u pixelima

#    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    # Provera za pritisnute tastere na tastaturi
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            playerX_change = -3
        #                print("Sistem je registrovao da je pritisnuta leva strelica")
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 3
    #                print("Sistem je registrovao da je pritisnuta desna strelica")
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            playerX_change = 0
#               print("Sistem ceka unos sa tastature")

 # <-- ovaj deo, i ispod definise nas brod i neprijatelje da ne izlaze van ekrana

playerX += playerX_change

if playerX <- 0:
    playerX = 0
elif playerX >= 736:
    playerX = 736

enemyX += enemyX_change

if enemyX <- 0:
    enemyX_change = 0.4
    enemyY += enemyY_change
elif enemyX >= 736:
    enemyX_change = -0.4
    enemyY += enemyY_change

player(playerX, playerY)
enemy(enemyX, enemyY)
pygame.display.update()
```

What am I so far doing wrong to get down of the window and up about 2cm of black strap...
Comments are on Serbian so like IGRAC = PLAYER, NEPRIJATELJ = ENEMY , but the code is the same...

So far I don't want to move on if there is a bug or I don't know what. I've used 800x600 screen, with icon of 64px in 3 cases, icon for app, player icon and enemy. Also, sometimes enemy (neprijatelj) is moving very odd and slow, **and** I am getting **ERROR MESSAGE WHEN COMPILING:**

```
home/boris/Downloads/Python-3.8.5/python /home/boris/Desktop/OsvajacSvemira/main.py
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
/home/boris/Desktop/OsvajacSvemira/main.py:38: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required         (got type float).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  screen.blit(enemyImg, (x, y))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have new KINGSTONE 4GB of RAM and an i686 processor. So, I am not x64 or a cutting edge developer, I am a old-school guy at least regarding tech using, but, I am working with cutting edge technologies as long as they are x86.

Comment: The message you are getting is a deprecation warning and not an error message. It is happening because pygame is converting floats to int. I wouldn't worry about it too much at this stage. It doesn't affect your program.

Comment: Just pointing it out, there is no point in filling the screen if you are rendering a background image. Its just a waste of time

Comment: What about the black track inside of the window on up and down.

Comment: I tried running your code by replacing the images with surfaces, but I didn't see any black track, so I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I ran your code (had to replace images). It looks correct. No trail.

Comment: Thank you all! It seems that before running code, now on upgraded and reinstalled system works. It was my (as I assumed) graphic card and it's drivers since my FAVORITE computer that I LOVE to work on is 32bit one from 2000... :) But, 4Gb ram :) Idk, linux and itself just work smoothly than Windows 10 and x64 with 4Gb ram which I also have.

Answer (score 1):

The warning refers to the coordinate argument of [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). Floating point coordinates would mean that the origin of the [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is somewhere between the pixels in the window. This does not make much sense. The coordinates are automatically and implicitly truncated, and this is indicated by the warning.
[`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates to integral values:

```py
screen.blit(enemyImg, (round(x), round(y)))
```

Comment: I would agree that it doesn't make much sense. but - it seems it's a bug.

Comment: @MilanovicFUL No it is not a pygame bug. It is a bug in your application. The warning points out that there is no point in passing floating point coordinates to `blit`.